# Use overridePendingTransition with multiple screens

Tags: android, screen, android-screen-support, android-screen, overridependingtransition

I'm trying to use `overridePendingTransition` in my `app` but I'm using multiples `screens` in the same `xml` (I'm programming a android game) and when I switch from one screen to another I use the `Visibility` property, in this case is there any way to use the `overridePendingTransition`?

Example:

```
void switchToScreen(int screenId) {

        // make the requested screen visible; hide all others.
        for (int id : SCREENS) {
            findViewById(id).setVisibility(screenId == id ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
```